# natural numbers satisfying the equation...

Tags: quadratics, natural-numbers

What is number of pairs of natural numbers $(x,y)$ which satisfy the equation $2x(xy-2y-3)=(x+y)(3x+y)$?

I factored the equation into a quadratic in $y$ and then use the discriminant(D) condition ($D \geq 0$ and $D$ should be a perfect square) but this is lengthy.

Could someone please suggest a simpler way. Thanks!

Comment: That's probably as simple as you can get.

Comment: Oh... use raional root theorem.

Comment: To possibly find restrictions or impossibilities, you might look at the equation mod 2 or mod 3... but a few minutes of this didn't yield anything easy to me.